# Android Studio : Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, nexus-4

I am new to Android Studio. I am trying to display what was entered as a pop up.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), input.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Error Log:

```
eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xac96ba80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa1705a0
```

Thanks!

Comment: try restarting your emulator

Answer (score 0):

try to use try catch.

```
try{
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), input.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}catch (IOError error){
error.printStackTrace();
}
```

do not forget to import `java.io.IOError;`